# can I buy an apple developer account with apple gift card?

Tags: ios

I am building apps with react native I just finished my first app , I have this simple question if you allow me to ask :
Can I Buy an apple developer account using apple gift card ?

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about a practical programming problem as outlined in the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3):

You cannot.

You can use a credit card or Apple Pay or PayPal.

[image: payment options]

Comment: what if a contry is not listed within list of contries ?